# Remove the black borders from a responsive video Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video, bootstrap-4

I would like to remove the black borders from a video and keep it responsive. I'm using Bootstrap 4.5. I would also like to keep the panoramic resolution of my video, 1920x764. I am almost sure that the problem has to do with the resolution. Should I then edit the bootstrap .css files?

```
<body>
    <!-- Video -->
    <!-- XLG/LG - 21:9 aspect ratio -->
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9 cab-video">
        <video class="embed-responsive-item">
            <source src="video.mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <!-- MD - 16:9 aspect ratio -->
    <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 cab-video">
        <video class="embed-responsive-item">
            <source src="video.mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <!-- SM - 4:3 aspect ratio -->
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 cab-video">
        <video class="embed-responsive-item">
            <source src="video.mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <!-- XSM - 1:1 aspect ratio -->
    <div class="d-block d-sm-none embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1 cab-video">
        <video class="embed-responsive-item">
            <source src="video.mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <!-- Video -->

    <!-- Javascript files -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Do you have any idea how i can solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried inline styling and applying `border: none` to your required element?

Comment: @ElysianStorm yes I did, it does't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see, Bootstrap 4 have a list of [embed aspect ratios](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/#aspect-ratios). The proportions of `.embed-responsive-21by9` from this list determines in BS CSS this way:

```
.embed-responsive-21by9::before {
  padding-top: 42.857143%;
}
```

Looks like your resolution is not quite standard. Let's add a new class to your CSS (or to Bootstrap). Lets say it will be `.embed-responsive-19by7`. 1920=100%, 764=39.7916% (using **proportion 764 * 100 / 1920 = 36.79166**). So your additional CSS is

```
.embed-responsive-19by7::before {
  padding-top: 39.7916%;
}
```

Now your video will be

```
<!-- panoramic - 19:7 aspect ratio -->
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block embed-responsive embed-responsive-19by7 cab-video">
        <video class="embed-responsive-item">
            <source src="video.mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
```

Comment: ooo thank you very much, that solved my problem. How did you calculate the padding?

Comment: Like I said in answer, If 1920 is 100%, then 764 is 39.7916%. Simple proportion. 764*100/1920=36.79166